# Batch To Find File, Copy File, then Rename File from a CSV

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, copy, rename

**Goal:** To obtain images with the same name as column B:

[image: My Excel File]

I currently have the images in column A stored locally as JPEGS.  I also have an excel document with the files that need to be renamed.  I want to:

1. Copy Image from folder (ie. BEVBB48GSY1B.jpg)
2. Rename File to next cell in the rows text (ie. BEV-BB48GSY1B.jpg)
3. Automatically move on to the next Row to do the same (ie. BEVBB48GSY1B copied and renamed to BEV-BB48GSY1B27)

Any ideas on which programming I need to be using or where to start?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since I see the `batch` tag in there: You want to use a batch file on the CSV file saved by Excel?

Comment: Retagged. I think you're going to want to use vbscript.

Comment: Is it is a csv this should be too difficult with ruby or perl. (Probably any scripting language would be straightforward to do it),but I know for sure it would be "easy" in those two.

Comment: I would use either PowerShell or Perl, but if you are stuck on using a Batch file, check out the `for` command (Look at examples for parsing). http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: @jwir3 why not batch? This can quite well be done using batch script as well!

Comment: @adarshr My understanding is that this *isn't* a csv file - it's an excel file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple batch script should do.

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%j in (your.csv) do (
    rename "path\to\images\%%j.jpg" %%k.jpg
)
```

It will print out an error for the first line of the CSV (which is actually the column header). Just ignore it.

Comment: You can add `skip=1` to the `for` options to avoid the error.

Comment: Ok this works fine, but it only renames instead of copying and pasting first then renaming file.  It will say it cannot find file because it renamed the first one.  Any idea how I can get it to copy and paste that file then rename it?

Comment: I got it I modified it to do:
`@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%j in (project.csv) do (
    copy "%%j.jpg" c:\mytestproject\newimages 
    rename "c:\mytestproject\newimages\%%j.jpg" %%k.jpg
)`

Comment: Does this work on Windows 10 v1909?
 

I get errors saying:
'The system cannot find the file specified.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.'