# Batch to find file, copy file to another directory

Tags: csv, batch-file, copy

My question is very similar to the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183853/batch-to-find-file-copy-file-then-rename-file-from-a-csv) on stackoverflow but the difference for me is that I need the batch script to do the following

1. Look at a csv file which has the name only without the image extension and find the image with that name in a particular directory
2. Then take that file and copy it to another directory

What modifications would I need to do to this batch script to accomplish that task?

```
 @echo off 
 for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%j in (project.csv) do ( 
   copy "%%j.jpg" c:\mytestproject\newimages 
   rename c:\mytestproject\newimages\%%j.jpg" %%k.jpg 
 )
```

Comment: Hmmm. The original script copies a file and renames it. You only want to copy the file. I wonder which line should be removed from the script?

Comment: Thank you for making the code better to read. The original script knew that the file in question was a .jpg which in my case I do not know but wanted whatever file that had that name in the .csv to be found and copied to another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Batch file assumes that the .CSV file contains just one field per line: the name, with NO extension, of a file that exist, with ANY extension, in a particular directory, so it copy that file to another directory.

```
@echo off
set "theDir=C:\The\Particular\Directory"
for /F "delims=" %%f in (theFile.csv) do (
   copy %theDir%\%%f.* "C:\another\Directory"
)
```

If you want the image file have an extension taken from a limited list:

```
@echo off
set "theDir=C:\The\Particular\Directory"
for /F "delims=" %%f in (theFile.csv) do (
   for %%e in (jpg png) do (
      if exist "%theDir%\%%f.%%e" copy "%theDir%\%%f.%%e" "C:\another\Directory"
)
```

Comment: your first file answers what was necessary to accomplish what I was needing

Answer (score 0):

You can check for existence of a file with `if exist`. So in your loop:

```
if exist "%%j.jpg" copy "%%j.jpg" target
if exist "%%j.png" copy "%%j.png" target
```

Comment: But that would move the file instead of copying it correct? And if the file exist, is it possible to create a csv listing of the files it finds using this method

Comment: Of course it is possible. Just print whatever you desire with `echo`.

Comment: so this should look like this then `@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," if exist "%%j.jpg" if exist "%%j.png" in (test.csv) do ( copy "%%j.jpg", "%%j.png" c:\mytestproject\newimages `

Comment: I'm not sure what the comma is doing in there. I guess that's invalid syntax for `copy`. You may actually just start reading the help. Currently I don't really understand your requirements.

Comment: does the question make sense now